# <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.xxxxxxl.com/index.php" /> is not refreshing

Tags: php, html

I had a (very) simple login script which was working beautifully, and somehow, without much, if any, changes on the script page I have the following error:

**The Problem**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php" />
```

The above code is not refreshing, which means the user is not getting redirected after login. He/she has to manually refresh the page to start his/her session:

[image]

As you can see from above image, the login was successful, but the page isn't refreshing.

Please note using `header("location:")` is not an option here:

Also note I'm using Ajax with the form submission for what that is worth...

Part of the login script:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // Do stuff
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) = 1) {
        while
        {
            // GET session variables
        }//while
        echo 'Success! Logging In....';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.xxxxx.com/index.php" />'//now refresh page
    } //if
} //if
```

Strangely, this was working for me above, but it has since yesterday stopped working.

**Solution**

Is there a reason why this is not working?

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Is there any alternative approach?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't add header information like that. You need to use javascript to refresh the page.

Comment: Agree with Codeguy007. Just change your echo to use: echo 'window.location.reload(true)';

Comment: @Sasha but Im trying not to go with javascript

Comment: @Codeguy007 That's not an HTTP header, it's HTML (not very clean one though).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp meta tags go in the header as such they can not be changed after the html page has been loaded by the browser.

Comment: @Codeguy007 You're confusing HTTP with HTML, and HTTP headers with HTML's `<header>` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are trying to do it will not work, because the `<meta>` tag is supposed to come in the `<head>` section of your page, not in the body. Plus, you can't use `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` or any other header directives once output is sent.

Try replacing this part:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.xxxxx.com/index.php" />'
```

with this:

```
echo '<script>location.href="http://www.xxxxx.com/index.php"</script>';
```

Comment: Please provide a reason why the first approach doesn't work and why the second one does, to make the answer more complete.

Comment: Ok im trying it and letting you know soon

Comment: As much as this will likely work, it does require your users to have javascript enabled, whereas your `<meta>` tag does not.

Comment: It doesnt work with `<script>` tag and I agree with @MattieTK about the script

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee, You are making use of AJAX. that's the issue. You need to return a success flag to your front end script on successful login, and use that to do the redirect using javascript.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer so in other words something like this `'window.location.reload(true)`

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee, Yes, if the current page has a way to detect if the current user is logged-in and serve them user-only content. No, if that's not the case, in which case you'd have to use `location.href=THE_URL_TO_REDIRECT_USER`, of course `THE_URL_TO_REDIRECT_USER` should be in quotes.

Comment: Thanks I got it working just 3 very daft questions: 1)What will happen if user doesnt have jscript enabled? 2)I didnt know you can use `<script>` tag inside PHP 3) Would it not be better to use the `<noscript>` tag

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee: 1)That's where the principle of "progressive enhancement" comes in, though majority of users have javascript turned on. 2) You can use PHP to output any HTML tag, and the `<script>` tag happens to be an HTML tag, once sent to the browser, the browser interpretes the content between the `<script></script>` tag. 3)That decision will be based on the model you have adopted for your project.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing all the technologies you are using to build your site. In the end you have nothing but plain HTML and it should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://www.google.com/">
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Redirecting in 5 seconds...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

How you generate this code is irrelevant from the browser point of view.

Browsers are designed to be very permissive about invalid HTML and you've pushed it to the limit. Yet both Firefox and Chrome see to handle even this just fine:

```
Not redirecting
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://www.google.com/"></head>
```

So there must be something else you haven't shared.

Having said that, this is the weirdest way to redirect. I didn't even know people were still using it in 2015. Since you have PHP, leverage it:

```
header('Location: http://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php');
exit;
```

Comment: fair point, Im using a pop up modal box when user clicks `log in` when I use `header('Location: http://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php');` the whole webpage re-loads inside the modalbox....hench using the above `<meta http>` tag

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to use PHP to change the headers:

`header( "refresh:0;url=index.php" );` instead of your `echo` for the meta tag

Comment: Is there really a `refresh` HTTP header?